# Access Repository from a BackgroundJob called inside a Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, hangfire

I'm new to hangfire and have minimal knowledge on .net-core itself. So I was tasked to create a recurrent background job which updates a specific column on a table. I stumbled upon hangfire and chose to use it. I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html) and updated methods like so:

**Startup.cs:**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add Hangfire services.
    services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseSqlServerStorage(_appConfiguration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
            UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
            UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
            DisableGlobalLocks = true
        }));

    // Add the processing server as IHostedService
    services.AddHangfireServer();
    . . . . . . . 

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobs, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); // Initializes ABP framework.

    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    . . . .
```

Now, what I did was create a class library which will process the background jobs to be run and calls it like so:

**Startup.cs:**

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Hangfire services.
        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
               . . . .
        );

        // Add the processing server as IHostedService
        services.AddHangfireServer();

        //this one ↓
        //process backgroundjobs queue
        var jobInit = new JobsInitiator(_appConfiguration);
        jobInit.InitiateQueue();
```

**JobsInitiator.cs:** (This class is in a Class Library project outside my app's Web.Host project)

```
public class JobsInitiator {
        private readonly IMonitoringApi _monitoringApi;

        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        public JobsInitiator(IConfiguration _config) {
            Configuration = _config;
            JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"));
            _monitoringApi = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
        }

        public void InitiateQueue() {
            List<BackgroundJobBase> jobs = GetJobsForQueue();

            foreach (BackgroundJobBase job in jobs) {
                string jobName = job.JobName;
                RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobName, () => job.StartJob(), Helper.GetRecurrenceFromConfig(Configuration, jobName));
                //Hangfire.Storage.Monitoring.JobDetailsDto jobDetails =  _monitoringApi.JobDetails(jobName);
            }
        }

        public List<BackgroundJobBase> GetJobsForQueue() {
            List<BackgroundJobBase> jobs = new List<BackgroundJobBase>();

            // Add background jobs here...
            jobs.Add(new Jobs.SomeJobToBeDone(Configuration));

            return jobs;
        }
    }
```

Now I'm in a roadblock. I can't wrap my head around on how to access the repositories I need so I can update the tables I want. Am I doing this right? Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Where is your repository classes. If they are in the Main project which have referance to the class library including JobsInitiator class, you cannot. Because you have referance only one direction and in your case you can access to class library from your main project. If you have another class library including your reposiyories, you can add referance to your class library(the one including JobsInitiator) to access to Repository Layer.